# Get list of TeamCity idle agents

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, teamcity

I am developing a web app (WebForms/C#) where I need to get some extra info about TeamCity agents.
For example:
[image: Idle Agents]

For now I need get list of available agents which are currently in idle state.
I am trying to do this over [REST API Plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin), but no luck...

Is that possible to do via REST?

**NOTE:** I am not interested in number of idle agents. I need ability to get complete info about each idle agent (e.g. - name/ip, current state, etc)

Can anybody advice me in what way I need dig? I'll like also to ask code snippets for provided solutions.

Comment: The API doc link you posted has a section regarding agents [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin#RESTAPIPlugin-Agents) and specifically a "list of connected agents" - without knowing the API, I'm guessing you can tweak this to get your idle ones.

Comment: No, that would not help. Agent can have statuses - Connected/ Disconnected, Authorized/Unauthorized, Enabled/Disabled. Those statuses does not tell me if agent is really idle for further processing. For example agent can be Disabled but still run the build conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no direct methods on `Agent` to get if the status is idle.

RE: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin#RESTAPIPlugin-Agents

However, I suppose you could first get the names of all connected agents (and the rest of the fields such as IP, etc.):

`GET http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/agents?includeDisconnected=false`

Then loop through each agent to determine if it is running:

`GET http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=running:true,agentName:BuildAgent1`

If it is not running, it is idle. Report all fields for each idle agent.

https://github.com/stack72/TeamCitySharp is an open source .net library wrapping the api. Might be useful for your app.

Comment: Wow, dude, this is exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks! TeamCitySharp looks interesting. Need to try it.